# Executor OutOfMemoryExceptions on small data size vs available memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory, rdd

Given a simple case class

```
  case class Rating(user: Int, item: Int, rating: Double)
```

and two `RDD[Rating]`:  we are getting OOME's with about 7 million entries between the two RDD's.

We have configured a *single* executor with 30.4GB RAM.  That is a ***huge*** overhead on each `Rating` entry. I can not justify it:  the raw primitives for Int and Double are 8 bytes on a 64bit platform.  Then there will be overhead for the java representation of same and also for the Case Class.  But all told we should still be < 200 bytes for a single `Rating` entry in the JVM.

Given 30.4GB RAM and 7M objects - then the apparent memory usage would be over **4KB** per object. That does not compute.

Here is the cluster and job info showing 30.4GB for the single executor:

[image]

Note that we have also enabled  `kryo` serialization by registering the `Rating` class in the `KryoSerializer` and enabled

```
 spark.rdd.compress=true
```

These have not affected the OOME's.

Is the `RDD` representation bloating the memory usage a great deal more?  Or is the issue that the majority of the executor RAM were not being used at all for this - and the OOME is happening due to some other reason(s)?

Here is the resulting OOME - which happens just a few seconds into the job:

```
[Dec 06 22:37:32] Generated an implicit feedback dataset with 4501305 ratings for training and 2247105 for test.
Generated dataset in 2644ms
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 2]Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.write(ObjectOutputStream.java:1852)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.write(ObjectOutputStream.java:708)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SerializableBuffer$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(SerializableBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SerializableBuffer$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(SerializableBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1219)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SerializableBuffer.writeObject(SerializableBuffer.scala:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$anonfun$launchTasks$1.apply(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$anonfun$launchTasks$1.apply(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:225)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint.launchTasks(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint.org$apache$spark$scheduler$cluster$CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$makeOffers(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:123)
```

Note: if we use slightly fewer data - e.g. an `RDD` with 5 million `Rating`s then the job completes relatively quickly (< 40seconds) and successfully.

So we are uncertain what factors are limiting the usefulness of the spark worker to such low memory constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The larger portion of the issue appears to be that the `DRIVER` program were requiring far more RAM than anticipated.

The Driver program is not doing any `collect`, `take`, `groupBy` etc but only `count` 's .  Not sure why `count` would require significant resources on the Driver.   More details will be added here as we narrow down the driver details.